# How to use Mysql Slave DB for SonataAdminBundle list & show pages?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, sonata-admin, master-slave

I am using Symfony2 and SonataAdminBundle for my backend system. The data is gradually increasing which is slowing down my backend system. I have looked/searched for SonataAdminBundle optimization and found that many Users complained about Sonata's pagination issues for slow performance.The backend queries are taking much time hence slowing down my Mysql Master DB.

Now what I want?

I want to generate all my List & Show pages i.e. "/list" & "/show" pages using Mysql Slave connection, so that all the SELECTS run on my Mysql Slave DB and for Inserts & Update I want to use Mysql Master DB.

Is it doable? Can anyone suggest me / give me any clue?

Many thanks ..